# convert query obj data to datetime obj

Tags: django

writing a management command that deletes records more than two weeks old.
each model instance has a ‘confirmed_placed’ which I’m using as the comparison date.
(‘confirm_placed’ is a CharField because it’s generated dynamically in a predetermined format).

If my Item model looks like:

```
class HotItem(models.Model):
    item_no = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    ad_date = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    create_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=210, blank=True, null=True)
    comments = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True) 
    reply = models.TextField(max_length=2000, blank=True, null=True)
    confirmed_placed = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default=None)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.create_date, self.item_no, self.item_name, self.confirmed_placed, self.comments)
```

What I need is the proper way to convert my objects confirmed_placed value to a date time obj and compare against twoweeksago (as defined below.) Something like:

```
from .models import HotItem as Item

twoweeksago = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(weeks=2)


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Delete hotlist items placed more than two weeks ago'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        **hotrecords = Item.objects.filter(datetime.datetime.strptime(confirmed_placed.replace('.','').replace(',',''),' %b %d %Y')__gt=twoweeksago)**

        for record in hotrecords:
            record.delete()

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully deleted record old records'))
```

any ideas on the proper way to format the query?

Comment: This seems strange. Why isn't confirm_placed a DateTimeField? Your explanation that it is "generated dynamically" doesn't really help, anything that is generated dynamically could just as easily be saved as a datetime.

Comment: I'm checking now. confirmed_placed refers to images; specifically, the file mod date created when the file is uploaded into our system. The Item instance is created programmatically by a script that periodically trawls the servers and adds new images. Investigating the implications of converting the format to a proper DateTimeField as your comment suggests this is what makes the most sense.

Comment: Edited the scraper to format the date string correctly. Converted the model field to a DateField. Now my query operator is comparing apples to apples and the code is functioning properly. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.